# download the latest file from (bunch of files) a website using selenium webdriver python

Tags: python

I wanted to download most recent file from 'https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/328a303b-8bf8-4c9d-9285-c8b25ce18fe0'. usually the latest file has prefix of (currentdate-1). it is 05-23-2022.zip at this point.
when I ran the below sample code:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.set_preference("browser.download.folderList", 2)
options.set_preference("browser.download.manager.showWhenStarting", False)
options.set_preference("browser.download.dir", "/a/b/c")
options.set_preference("browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk", "application/force-download")

driver = webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
driver.get('https://mft.rrc.texas.gov/link/328a303b-8bf8-4c9d-9285-c8b25ce18fe0')
elem = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value="//a[text()='05-23-2022.zip']")
```

I can only download the files available on first page (the webpage has pagination and we can only see 250 files by default). the file I am intended to download is not coming in the first 250. hence it is throwing an error as below:

selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: //a[text()='05-23-2022.zip']

1)the problem here is the website has pagination and how to download a file that was not placed in the first page?
2) how to download all files from the webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just click on `last page` button before downloading to download last file:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# initiate driver ...

try:
  # go to last page
  wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
  last_page_btn = 
  wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-paginator-last")))
  last_page_btn.click()

  # do your stuff ...
finally:
  driver.quit()
```

To download all files you have to create for loop with actions below:

1. Get list of files:

   ```py
   files_list = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "ui-commandlink")))
   ```
2. iterate over files as `for file in files_list:` and download it all by clicking
3. go to next page (see code how to go to last page but change class name to `ui-paginator-next`)

Comment: Similarly, to download all files, you'd just loop over the pages and click the 'next' button until it is disabled. In both cases essentially what you would do if you were to do the task manually.

Comment: I put it in a loop over all pages and then loop over all files and its working.